# How do i read this raid information output?

Tags: linux, mount, devices, raid, lsblk

Im currently working on a remote ubuntu 18.04 server where i need to set up a new raid array (raid1) and then mount it as an available partition to the active filesystem. The first step for me is to understand what going on at the moment. I know that there are 2 hard drives inside the active system that are connected in a raid 1 array. I used the `lsblk` command to gather some information. The output is following:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 894,3G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     4G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0     4G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511,4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 889,8G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 889,6G  0 raid1 /
```

So does this mean tha tmy physical device is the one called `nvme0n1` ?
And this is partitioned in 3 pieces (swap, boot, and /). If its the same physical device (`nvme0n1`) why are the partitions (`nvme0n1p1,nvme0n1p2,nvme0n1p3`) furthermore seperated into `md0,md1,md2` ? What is the difference between `nvme0n1p1` and `md0` ?

If i `cat /proc/mdstat` i furthermore get following output:

```
md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[1]
      932840768 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 7/7 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[1]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      
md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[1]
      4190208 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
```

This show 3 active raidblocks. I only have one raid array running. I cannot interpret the output... i need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the full `lsblk` output, then I'm afraid it shows only one physical storage device, `nvme0n1`.

Your `nvme0n1` is partitioned into three partitions, each individually set up for software-RAID1 mirroring. That gives you three software-RAID devices: `md0`, `md1` and `md2`. Each of those corresponds to a single software-RAIDed partition, not a whole disk.

Setting up RAID per-partition like this makes the disk recognizable for BIOS as a partitioned disk, even as BIOS has no awareness of Linux software RAID at all. This can make booting and some recovery scenarios simpler to handle, and can allow easy reversion to a non-RAID configuration if needed.

In a normal, mirrored state, `md0` would refer to the mirrored set of `nvme0n1p1` + `nvme1n1p1`, `md1` to the set of `nvme0n1p2` + `nvme1n1p2`, etc. You would mount the filesystems and activate the swap using the `md0`, `md1` and `md2` devices: as soon as those devices are opened for use, the software-RAID subsystem would lock the underlying physical partitions for exclusive access, requiring all access to the partitions to go through the RAID layer while the RAID was active.

However, each of those software-RAID sets is missing the second half of a RAID1 pair. **This might mean the system was set up with software RAID on two identical NVMe devices, but one of those (probably `nvme1n1`) has already failed.** Or perhaps the system was set up on a single NVMe disk as one-half of a RAID1 set, to allow an easy transition to true RAID1 as soon as a second NVMe device could be obtained... but this never happened, for some reason or another.

Your first priority should probably be to replace the failing NVMe (or add the missing one), and then recover the existing RAID pairs:

- copy the partition table from the existing disk to the new disk
- initialize the partitions on the new disk as spares for the corresponding `mdN` device
- start the RAID1 recovery on each pair
- install a second copy of the bootloader to the second disk, as MBR and parts of GRUB are located outside the mirrored partitions.
- **set up monitoring for the RAID devices so that the failure of one of the physical devices will not go unnoticed again.**

Once that is done, you could think about your original task of setting up a new RAID array. To do that, you would need more physical storage, as it appears the existing `nvme0n1` is fully in use (and so will its mirror companion, once the current half-mirrors have been fully recovered).

Comment: Thank you very dearly for your advice ! So it would also be possible to just partition the single physical device (nvme0n1) into 3 pure raid partitions. They output would show md0-2 directly append from the root device, but the bios would actually not recognize it and only show the single root device since it is not aware of the raid software?

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, [the answers in this question on Server Fault might be useful to you.](https://serverfault.com/q/713647/442837) It is now possible to create [partitioned softRAID arrays out of whole disks](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Partitionable), but since the firmware will not understand them, you won't be able to boot from them. Such a setup would show just one RAID device e.g. `md0` in `/proc/mdstat`, but multiple devices like `/dev/md/d0p1`, `/dev/md/d0p2` and `/dev/md/d0p3` for use.

Comment: Concatenating several RAID devices on one physical block device would be technically possible but not auto-detectable: generally, if the kernel finds a soft-RAID element on a whole-disk or partition, but the element does not cover the whole capacity of the block device in question, the kernel assumes the left-over is currently unused. In practice, such situation usually happens when e.g. a SAN LUN or other type of virtual disk is being resized, and the expectation is that the empty space will soon vanish (when shrinking) or that the RAID element will soon be extended to cover it (expanding).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the output shows only one physical device (nvme0n1).

Yes the output shows it has 3 partitions.

The interesting part is the info from `/proc/mdstat`, where it shows the **3** configured raid devices, all of which are showing `[_U]`. In a healthy system it should say `[UU]`. The 3 raid devices are configured as raid1 (mirrored) and so the (presumed) failure of the second drive has not caused you any data loss yet. Of course the second drive might not be detected because it has been removed.

A study of the boot log might give you a hint if it sees a second drive at all.

nvme0n1p1 is a partition. It will have a raid header at the start. The rest of the sectors in the partition are used as data for the md0 device. If a second drive was connected, which might be a conventional `spinning rust` hard drive it would be expected that it would have at least 3 partitions, One of them (by convention you would have it the first so /dev/hda1) would also have a raid header and then the rest of the sectors would be used to hold a second copy of the data for the /dev/md0 device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So if you refer to "configured raid devices" what you actually mean are 3 virtual raid devices on one single physical device with 3 partitions the hold those 3 virtual raid devices. The partitions are the nvme0n1p1-3 and the md0-2 are like the identifications that those are inf act part of the raid set on the same single physical device ?

Comment: I just edited [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654522/258991) to try and clarify this. For example, `md0` would refer to the RAID set formed by `nvme0n1p1` and the now-missing `nvme1n1p1`, and any access to that RAID set (mounting a filesystem, activation of swap space, etc.) would normally be done through the `md0` device. The individual `nvme0n1p1` would only be usable when the RAID was stopped, and would normally only be needed for special purposes like debugging the RAID functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I think i know what to do now !